# Producing a moving time sequence in raster

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster that looks like this:

```
library(raster)

# Create data
set.seed(123)
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
r[] <- sample(10:360, ncell(r),replace = T)
crs(r) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"
projection(r)
plot(r)
```

[image]

For each grid, the raster contains a day of the year as values. I am looking for a method that generates a map (animation maybe) which goes from day 1 to day 365 and when the map reaches the day which matches with the day of a grid, the grid should turn green.

I am sorry but I cannot produce what I have tried since I have no clue whether such thing is possible in R.

Thank you

**EDIT**

One way I could think of is run a loop like this:

```
for(i in 2:365){

    breakpoints <- c(1,i,365)
    colors <- c("green4","white")
    plot(r, breaks = breakpoints,col=colors)
}
```

Save the ouptut of each loop as .png and then develop a .gif image of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a loop, you can `reclassify` your raster into a binary raster (0 if lower or equal to the day, 1 if higher). Then, you can use the `animation` package to create the gif.

```
library(animation)
ani.options(interval=.05)

saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:365){
    m <- c(1, i, 0,  i, 365, 1)
    rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
    rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)

    plot(rc, col=c("green3", "white"), legend=FALSE, main = paste("Day", i))
  }
})
```

**Demo** (200 days)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based off some of the code from DJack, you could also use Shiny to allow the user to select the day. If your raster had a proper spatial projection, you could then use Leaflet to overlay the Raster on an interactive map.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

set.seed(123)
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
r[] <- sample(10:360, ncell(r),replace = T)
crs(r) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"



ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Daily Raster!"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      sliderInput(inputId = "bins", label = "Day", min = 1, max = 365, value = 1)
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Histogram ----
      leafletOutput(outputId = "Raster")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Raster <- renderLeaflet({

    m <- c(1, input$bins, 0,  input$bins, 365, 1)
    rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
    rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)

    leaflet() %>% addRasterImage(rc)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]